# Using JDBI's onDemand syntax, do I need to close handles?

Tags: jdbi

Because I have some queries that are simple, and some that require special operations, in my project I'm using JDBI's Object api mixed with the fluid syntax, along with it's onDemand functionality like so:

```
public abstract class MyDAO implements GetHandle {

    @SqlQuery("SELECT anInt FROM aTable;")
    public abstract int getAnInt();

    public List<Integer> insertThings(List<Thing> things) {

        Handle h = getHandle();

        PreparedBatch batch = h.prepareBatch("INSERT INTO thingsTable (a, b) VALUES (?, ?)");

        for (Thing thing : things) {
            batch.add(things.getA(), thing.getB());
        }

        List<Integer> ids = batch.executeAndGenerateKeys(IntegerColumnMapper.WRAPPER).list();

        h.close();

        return ids;
    }
}

//Elsewhere in my code

MyDAO dao = jdbi.onDemand(myDAO.class);

dao.insertThings(things);
```

So my question is, when using JDBI in this manner do I need to make sure that I close my handle as I am in the example, or does the onDemand take care of the closing as it does in the abstract methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to close the handle when using onDemand.

From the documentation:

> The final method for obtaining a sql object instance will obtain and release connection automatically, as it needs to. Generally this means that it will obtain a connection to execute a statement and then immediately release it, but various things such as open transactions or iterator based results will lead to the connection remaining open until either the transaction completes or the iterated result is fully traversed.

See the end of this page: http://jdbi.org/sql_object_overview/

Comment: That's what I was thinking, my worry was just that since I was opening the handle outside of the usual flow, that I would have to close it myself as well.